Let $X$ and $Y$ be two matrices of order $3\times 2$ and $2\times 3$. Then Least value of $|YX|$ is

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two matrices of order $3\times 2$ and $2\times 3$ respectively such that
$XY=\begin{bmatrix} 
 2 & -2 & 0\\
 -2 & 2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 &2\\
 \end{bmatrix}$
Then Least value of $|YX|$ is
$|.|$ denotes determinant of a matrix.

My Approach:
Since order of $X$ and $Y$ are $3\times 2$ and $2\times 3$ respectively.
So order of $YX$ will be $2\times 2$
Now let $YX=A$ for convenience
Using Caley Hamilton Theorem:
$A^2-\text{trace}(A)\cdot A+|A|I_{2\times2}=0$
Applied trace both side
$\text{trace}(A^2)-(\text{trace}(A))^2+2|A|=0$
Now let eigen value of $A$ as $\alpha, \beta$ Hence eigen value of $A^2$ will be ${\alpha}^2, {\beta}^2$
Also $\text{trace}(XY)=\text{trace} (YX) =6$
So $2|A|=-\text{trace}(A^2)+(\text{trace}(A))^2$
After this I am not able to find least value of $|YX|$
Update Thanks, to @BrianMoehring and @Gribouillis
Since $\text{trace}(YX)^2=\text{trace}(YXYX)=\text{trace}{(XYXY)}=\text{trace}(XY)^2=20$
Hence $2|A|=36-20$
$\implies |A|=8$
Note: $(XY)^2=\begin{bmatrix} 
 8 & -8 & 0\\
 - 8& 8 & 0\\ 0 & 0 &4\\
 \end{bmatrix}$
If there is any other method to solve this problem then all solution as welcomed

You don't need Cayley-Hamilton to say that $|A| = \alpha\beta$. This is true because the eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial which is a monic polynomial.

Shouldn't you be able to determine the trace of both $A$ and $A^2$, and then solve for $|A|$?  Am I missing something?

@BrianMoehring Indeed $\text{tr}(YXYX) = \text{tr}(XYXY)$

Alternatively you can take the Cayley Hamilton equation you have with $\text{trace}(A) = 6$ filled in, multiply left by $X$ and right by $Y$ and then $B^3 - 6B^2 + \lvert A \rvert B = 0$ appears, where $B = XY$. Computing the matrix $-B^3 + 6B^2$ you should find that it is $8B$ so the determinant is 8, but then I do not understand what is meant by least value? It seems like you can just compute it exactly and not need to bound it

@BrianMoehring I got the answer as $8$. thanks

The matrix $(XY)^2$ that you wrote is incorrect.

@Gribouillis Edited

So you were almost there. You can take the Cayley Hamilton equation you found, $$A^2 - 6 A + \lvert A \rvert I =0,$$ multiply left by $X$ and right by $Y$ and so obtain $$B^3 -6B^2 + \lvert A \rvert B = 0$$ where $B = XY$ is the given matrix. Now you can compute $$-B^3 + 6B^2 = \lvert A \rvert B$$ and find that it is $8B$. The ''quick'' way to go about this (for instance on an exam/competition) would be to only care about the $(3,3)$ entry: by the block-diagonal nature of $B$ you find $$( -B^3 + 6B^2 )(3,3) = -2^3 + 6\cdot 2^2 = 16 = 8 B({3,3}) \implies \lvert A \rvert = 8.$$

What is meant by block diagonal nature of $B$

@mathophile So $B$ looks like a diagonal matrix but the diagonal entries are matrices. To make it precise, it is explained here in general: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices
In our case, you can write $B = \begin{bmatrix} B_1 & 0 \ 0 & B_2 \end{bmatrix}$, where $B_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -2 \ -2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ is the $2 \times 2$ matrix in the definition of $B$ and $B_2 = 2$.  Always in the case of block diagonal matrices (like ordinare diagonal matrices) you have that $B^n = \begin{bmatrix} B_1^n & 0 \ 0 & B_2^n \end{bmatrix}$

Remark that the rightmost $0$ in $B = \begin{bmatrix}B_1 & 0 \ 0 & B_2 \end{bmatrix}$ is actually a $1 \times 2$ zero matrix and the left most $0$ is a $2 \times 1$ zero matrix. In the case of a block diagonal matrix you always want the 'diagonal' blocks to be square.  A famous block diagonal matrix that is not just diagonal is the Jordan Normal Form of a matrix https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

The reason I added it is that you do not need to compute $-B^3 + 6B^2$ entirely by hand as that would take some time. In this case, you can just look at the bottom right entry and compute from there since in our case $$-B^3 + 6B^2 = \begin{bmatrix}-B_1^3 + 6B_1^2 & 0 \ 0 & -2^3 + 6\cdot 2^2 \end{bmatrix}$$

As an alternative proof note that
the eigenvalues of $X Y$ are $0, 2$ an $4$. If $\lambda\not = 0$ is one of the eigenvalues of $X Y$ and $U$ is a non-zero eigenvector, then
\begin{equation}
Y X (Y U) = Y (X Y U) = \lambda Y U
\end{equation}
hence $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $Y X$ for the eigenvector $Y U\not = 0$. It follows that the eigenvalues of $A = YX$ are $2$ and $4$. Hence
\begin{equation}
\det YX = 2\times 4 = 8
\end{equation}

what I did is incorrect?

@mathophile No, your proof is correct. This is just another way to do it.
